# Play Billing 5.0.0 Kotlin - How to override onProductDetailsResponse()?

Tags: android, kotlin, play-billing-library

please reference this [doc](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate#kts).

It states: "*To handle the result of the asynchronous operation, you must also specify a listener which implements the ProductDetailsResponseListener interface. You can then override onProductDetailsResponse(), which notifies the listener when the query finishes, as shown in the following example:*"

Trouble is, there's no such listener in the Kotlin example (there is one in the Java example.)

When I add:

```
override fun onProductDetailsResponse() { ... }
```

I get "nothing to override" from the SDK. Is it the case that Java needs the interface but Kotlin doesn't?

Thank you!

Comment: Its a listener that is added to `billinngClient.queryProductDetailsAsync` method, the lambda is actually the `ProductDetailsResponseListener`.

Comment: Thank you. So that example is good as is, right? I don't need to add listener code? (of course I need to process the result.) It's working fine I just want to ensure I'm reading/doing this right.

Comment: Yes, the example is correct. The lambda `{ billingResult, productDetailsList -> }` is the `ProductDetailsResponseListener` since the example is in Kotlin.